# Customize profile card in Microsoft 365

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft365

Is it possible to extend or create a new tab in the profile card for Microsoft 365 when hovering over the person image. I want to have one icon placed on red area spot and once the user click on it, should navigate to a dedicated page or change the content in profile card itself.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but I did some research and, if I understood your question correctly, I have a couple of Microsoft articles that you might find helpful:

[Add additional properties to the profile card using the profile API in Microsoft Graph](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-search-blog/add-additional-properties-to-the-profile-card-using-the-profile/ba-p/1496467)

[onPremisesExtensionAttributes resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onpremisesextensionattributes?view=graph-rest-beta)

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the reply but I am not looking just to show custom Profile properties rather a custom hierarchical chart build using react, angular or vue that should showup in Profile card itself or a link so that when user click from Profile card it should redirect them to custom page.

Comment: Okay. Sorry, I can't really help you there. Good luck!